# cannot submit address to Google geocoder on iPad: ArcGIS JS webmap app

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding, google-maps-api, ios, ipad

I am working on a web map app for desktop and iPads.  The app uses a Google geocoder to locate addresses or intersections, added with the standard code in 'init':

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

Everything about the geocoder works fine on my desktop using IE9, Chrome, or Firefox 20.0.  But on an iPad (I am testing with one using v 5.1), I cannot submit the address I type in the text box...The 'Go(enter)' button does nothing, and no clicks or presses on the screen do anything.  Oddly, I can enter and successfully search for addresses using the same app on an iPad mini, by pressing 'Go' (v 6.1.3) ...

Has anyone encountered this problem, or does anyone have any suggestions? I am brand new at testing for iOS! I can add the geocoder code, but there is kind of a lot of it..I don't think the error is in the geocoder setup, but I am not sure... // J

Comment: Test in firefox with the userAgent add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/useragentupdater/ and select iOS - use firebug to debug.

Comment: see this for source code - http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/ a little dated but helpful info.